Add custom component into specific feed tab
Issue:
I have a custom aura component and I want to add that or show that only when Email tab is clicked.

The orange color box is my custom component and i added that into feed.
but now its displaying common for all tabs.
I want to display it when user click Email(standard) tab only.
Is there any way to do this using JavaScript to identify the email tab click in my custom component?
Additional Information:
Aura component is added into Case object via Lightning page builder.

I tried with lightning:quickActionAPI but was not able to get the id of another quick action or click events. Reference
Suggestion: You might need to build a custom implementation for this whole.

Hi raditz2077
No the email tab is the standard tab which is in Feed

There is no connection between the Feed items and my custom component. But I want to show my custom component when Email tab is clicked

Kindly can you clarify how have you have added custom aura component. Is it from Case >> Case Page Layout >> Feed View ?
From my research we can only add visual force pages to it. Let me know if the understanding is correct and i would suggest to update the question for the same. So better clarification to others too. I will edit and update the answer based on this.

my custom component is a aura component. I add that component into case feed via
Case -> Light builder page-> add the component into case feed.

For standard lightning quick action that is already present we are not able to get the id or any click event on that one. So if you want some functionality like this you might need to build a custom component showing the warning message and a email component within the same.
